# In Confluence, search for comments with a tag, and replies

Tags: search, tags, confluence

I want to add suggestions in the form of comments in different pages of a Confluence space, and provide a page listing all those comments.
I specified a tag for each comment ("doc_suggestion") and created a page which mainly features the search, as follows:

```
  <ac:structured-macro ac:macro-id="5e359315-32ff-45e6-848c-53cf2eda6725" ac:name="search" ac:schema-version="1">
    <ac:parameter ac:name="query">"doc_suggestion"</ac:parameter>
    <ac:parameter ac:name="type">comment</ac:parameter>
  </ac:structured-macro>
```

(Created with the editor UI using **+** button > **Other Macros** > **Search results**)

This does list the tagged comments, but not the replies made to those comments.

Is there a way to specify that I want comments containing **doc_suggestion**, plus any comments replying to such comments?